# Three simple makefile questions

Tags: c++, makefile

I have just been introduced to makefiles (for c++ programs) and I have three quick questions. Say that I have some class definition stored in functions.h, its definitions defined in functions.cpp and its implementation in main.cpp. My easy makefile is then:

```
CXX=g++

main: functions.o main.o
   ${CXX} -o main student.o main.o

clean: 
   rm -f *.o main
```

What I think is going on is that when I call make, it defaults to main and looks for the .o files. If they do not exist, then the makefile automatically creates the .o files and then executes the linking into main. First of all, why do we bother with all this when we can simply do

```
${CXX} -o main functions.cpp main.cpp
```

I started looking into macros, and I found a way to re-implement my makefile:

```
main: functions.o main.o
   ${CXX} $^ -o $@
```

where I presume the $^ and $@ automatically filled in main and the object files respectfully? How did it know to get this information?

My last question is why did the order change? My origin makefile had the format g++ -o [name] [dependents] while the one with the macros had g++ [name] -o [dependents]. I tried switching the order, but then the makefile stopped working. Why the switch?

Comment: I would drop `make` in favour of `cmake` or `conan` tbh. If you goal however is to learn how to program in make, then go for it

Answer (score 3):

You have a lot of questions here.  I'll try to answer them for you.

> First of all, why do we bother with all this when we can simply do
>
> ${CXX} -o main functions.cpp main.cpp

Yes, you can do that, too.  Sometimes it's more convenient to separate the compilation phase from the linking phase but you don't have to do that.

> How did it know to get this information?

$@ expands to the name of the rule that is being invoked.  In this case the name of the rule is `main`.  $^ expands to the names of all of the prerequisites (everything after the `:` on the rule line.)  In this case, $^ expands to `functions.o main.o`.  If you expand the rule and expand the macros you get:

```
main: functions.o main.o
    ${CXX} functions.o main.o -o main
```

> My last question is why did the order change?

It doesn't matter if you write the command as:

```
${CXX} functions.o main.o -o main
```

or as:

```
${CXX} -o main functions.o main.o
```

They are equivalent.  Now you can probably see that you misunderstood how the macros were expanded.

All of this is explained in the [GNU Make manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/) which is tedious to read but very informative.

Answer (score 0):

1a. Your assumption is correct. GNU make is executing built-in rules to convert your .c files to .o files. The it runs your explicit rule to link the .o files together.

1b. Why take two steps (one to compile and another to link)? They are distinct steps that just so happen to be both supported by the g++ compiler. This is a convenience that g++ provides. But there are many ways to create .o files. Some might be from .c files, others from .cpp files, and still others could come from another language, like Fortran. In all these cases, the compile step is different, but the link step is the similar. So splitting the build into two steps helps manage these differences.

2. Correct, these are automatic variables: https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Automatic-Variables.html
   $@ is replaced with the target of the rule and $^ is replaced with the list of all pre-requisites of the rule.
3. There is a slight difference to the commands. Your first is "g++ -o main functions.cpp main.cpp" and your second is "g++ functions.o main.o -o main". The first command is doing two steps (compile and link) and the second command is just linking. In general, the order of command-line arguments doesn't matter for tools like g++. However, I think in this case for linking, the .o files need to come before the output file option.

Comment: " I think in this case for linking, the .o files need to come before the output file option.". They don't.

Answer (score 0):

The one question that is not addressed adequately in the other answers, IMO, is why compile and link separately. For a small project like this it doesn't matter a whole lot, really. But for a large project the difference can be very significant.

Note that

```
${CXX} -o main functions.cpp main.cpp
```

will always compile both source files, link them together, and discard the object files (.o). In contrast,

```
${CXX} -o main functions.o main.o
```

will only link the object files. Make will detect when an object file is out of date and recompile it. Object files that are not out of date don't need to be recompiled.

The compilation step can take a long time. Especially for C++ with heavily templated code. Linking, in contrast, is usually quite fast even for larger projects.

If, in your large project, you modify one source file, there is no need to re-compile all other source files. By separating compilation and linking in your makefile, you ensure that `make` will only compile the one source file you changed, saving you lots of time in the development cycle.